# Memory overflows when streaming data using Bokeh push_notebook()

Tags: python, ipython, bokeh

It seems that there is a memory leak when calling push_notebook() for streaming data to a Bokeh plot in an IPython notebook. You can reproduce it with the following code in an IPython notebook cell:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
import numpy as np

output_notebook()

x = np.linspace(0., 1000., 1000)
p = figure()
hold()
p.line(x = x, y = np.sin(x), name = 'y')

def update():
    renderer = p.select(dict(name='y'))
    ds = renderer[0].data_source
    ds.data['y'] = np.sin(a * x)
    ds.push_notebook()

show(p)

a = 1.
while True:
    update()
    a *= 1.1
```

Not sure if it's supposed to be used that way though.

Comment: David, welcome to SO!  Python generally doesn't "leak" in the sense that it won't lose a reference and be unable to reclaim it.  It looks like your example allocates lots and lots of objects without yield.  Generally, the GC should be able to recover those.  Does it not?  Are you concerned that this occupies too much memory?  or executes too slowly?

Comment: please provide the exact error trace.

Comment: It is not a Python issue, but maybe in the JavaScript communication between IPython and Bokeh. Both the browser (in my case Chromium) and IPython occupy more and more memory, and eventually the system swaps.

Comment: This is almost certainly on the client (JS) side, rather than anything to do with python, per se. I have created an issue to look into the problem here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1732

Comment: Can you provide info about the bokeh and ipython version in the github issue? I tried with bokeh and ipython master and I saw a lot of memory used but did not see further failure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug listed here for this issue.
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1732